# reconstructing data on a noisy channel?

Tags: feistel-network

I have an interesting situation where I have a block cipher and a noisy channel.  The interesting thing is that I happen to know much about the data.  The cipher is a balanced Feistel network, and for the sake of this question, let's just assume that the block size is 32-bits.

What I know:

```
The key.
The original data has the format of xx000000, where xx is 8 bits of data.
```

It then gets encrypted.

The issue is that after encryption, I'm losing 2 bits of the 32-bit stream.  I have plenty of computer power, so I guess that I could just do a comparison because I know that xx will be 0-255 and run some sort of algorithm for flipped bits.

My question is: does anyone know if someone has looked into this before?  I feel that something like this would be a nice math project.

Comment: You can add error coding to the encrypted data.

Comment: That's my current plan, but the problem seemed to be an interesting academic exercise.  Mainly, because I know what 3/4 of the original data is.  I'll probably just waste bandwidth for a Reed Solomon encoder.

Comment: @bdegnan You *already know* that 24 out of 32 bits is `00` and you are worrying about the bandwidth? OK, academic exercises are always a good excuse, but practically I'd compress the input and then add error correction code.

Comment: I'm worrying about bandwidth because that's actually my prime constraint.  I don't think it can be helped  This is an academic exercise, but it's also a point of curiosity.     There just seemed to something interesting that could be done without an explicit channel coding scheme due to that fact that I knew so much about what was being sent.

Comment: If the cipher is any good, it's indistinguishable from a PRP.  If there's an approach better than trying all possibilities I think it would suggest a weakness in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Hadamard code via the fast Walsh Hadamard transform, it can correct up to $2^{n-2}$ errors for block length $2^n$ and is also locally decidable so you may not need too many code word coordinates.